# Visual Studio 2017 project template descriptions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, project-template

There are a lot of project templates for Visual Studio. I am new enough to programming that the little blurb of a description given in the new project window just doesn't give me enough information. Is there a place (perhaps online) where you can see detailed descriptions of all the visual studio project templates, and when to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the project types is all over the place. You can find them all on MSDN when you search for them, but not in one place. Visual Studio is extensible and some projects are added by SQL Server, some are added by BizTalk, some are added by Xamarin and each of these is "optional" and may not be installed in your Visual Studio or not available in your edition. You'll find their descriptions in each of these documentation areas.

The best way to start is probably to figure out what you want to do, find that on the MSDN documentation and in the docs you'll find a number of tutorials on what kind of project type to create.